# IBM Worklight JSON Store with Sync

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am getting the error when i tried run Worklight Application JSON Store with Sync

```
2013-05-15 10:27:43.466 OffApp[935:c07] [LOG] 16 Error Message: COULD_NOT_GET_SECURE_KEY
```

The JSON Store is failing to load initial Data From Adapter

Comment: Edit your question with more information: which environment did you try to run this? is it the sample app or your own app? add your code where you handle the JSONStore...

Answer (score 0):

That error message is saying your application that is using JSONStore is unable to reach the Worklight Server. It's trying to access `/random` to get a secure random token.

```
response [/apps/services/random] success: e9097576c8663f4d9946c9389570ff34bf81975c
```

That token is used to generate the keys necessary to provide data encryption.

The function called to generate the secure random is:

```
WL.EncryptedCache.secureRandom(callback);
```

**Edit (Feb. 6, 2014):** You can do the following to init without the Worklight Server:

```
WL.JSONStore.init(..., {localKeyGen: true});
```

More details in the documentation for init.